# How is the serving of public assets different in development and production modes of a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running the same rails 5.1.5 app in development and production. Everything works as expected in the development environment. In production, I could not serve the static assets in the public folder initially. I set the config.public_file_server.enabled = true in production.rb. However, since every request on my page is behind an authorization (as a :before_action in the application controller),  the .js file that sets the authorization cookie is also not served without authorization and my service is caught in a loop. This does not happen in the development mode, and the public assets are not requested through rails routes. I need guidance on how the serving of public assets is different in development and production mode for a rails application.

Comment: Take a look at this :
https://makandracards.com/makandra/8951-rails-asset-pipeline-why-things-break-in-production-and-what-precompilation-does-to-your-assets

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe this could be due to a problem in your production configuration. For an example in Production you don't let static resources to be served by the Rails process. You should instead set static assets to be served by the Web server. You cam simply do this by adding the following configuration to you Apache or Nginx virtual files.

DocumentRoot /home/xxx/test/public

root /var/www/phindee/current/public;

Comment: In both development and production, I am having rails serve the static resources, as Puma has no provision for serving static files(to the best of my knowledge). Why is the routing bypassed in development but not in production?